# MySQL query does not execute if i use the Stored Procedure parameter in the query

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I am creating a very simple store procedure with a query, but when i use the store procedure IN parameter in the query it gets stuck and does not execute the query, but if i put the value direct to the query it works.

This works:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `cap-reports`.ffap_test()
BEGIN
     select * FROM students WHERE name='Fernando';
END
```

This does not, i spent 10 minutes and it never returned

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `cap-reports`.ffap_test(IN pName VARCHAR(10))
BEGIN 
    select * FROM students WHERE name=pName;
END

call `cap-reports`.ffap_test('Fernando');
```

What mistake i am doing here? I never had this problem before

Comment: What happens if you replace pname in the `where` of your 2nd procedure with a constant (so you call the procedure with a parameter, but then do not use it). What does happen if you do `select * FROM students WHERE name='Fernando'; call ffap_test('Fernando');` at the exact same place as your current call (so first do the select, then do the call). Also, how are you executing your code, (e.g. how do you determine that it gets stuck - do you e.g. call it from mysql workbench and it does not return an output, do you have a php page and it shows a blank page, ...).

Comment: If I execute like you said `select * FROM students WHERE name='Fernando'; call ffap_test('Fernando');` it works fine.

Comment: The full store procedure i added 2 log inserts one before and one after the query, and it just log the one before the query

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, see [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3XZRpFYn84yFyJsub2nR3j/0).

Comment: Just to make sure: if you first do `select`, then `call`, it works (so it gives you the result twice, and it adds both logs), and if you just do the `call` it stops after the first call (so one log)? What exactly does "get stuck" mean? E.g. Timeout? MySQL will tell you some error after some time... wait that long and add it to your question. In general, what you are describing should not happen, and it seems you are missing some vital information about your setup, but I am not sure what that could be or what to test next (as a transaction lock could be excluded now)

Answer (score 0):

This procedure works for me. Maybe it's the difference in database of the procedure and the students table? Or a missing semi-colon?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `cap-reports`.ffap_test(IN pName VARCHAR(10))
BEGIN
    select * FROM `cap-reports`.members m WHERE m.Username = pName;
END
;

CALL `cap-reports`.ffap_test('winkbrace');
```